# Wordpress shortcode adding <br/> and <p> in text

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to use a popup plugin for wordpress (https://wordpress.org/plugins/anything-popup/). Problem is, it's adding breaks to my text when I try to use the shortcode in the middle of a sentence.

See here: http://www.universaltheosophy.com/secret-doctrine-lexicon/

What should read:

"The Secret Doctrine Lexicon is a project set up by..."

ends up with a rogue paragraph break. Here's what I see in the source-code:

`<p style="text-align: justify;"><i>The Secret Doctrine<br />
<style type="text/css">#AnythingPopup_BoxContainer2 ....`

Now, I've tried disabling wpautop and it didn't make any difference. I'm not versed in php, so I have no idea how to edit the plugin itself if that's where the problem is. Anyone willing and able to help me out with this? (the plugin has virtually no support)

Comment: do you really need to embed about 6 miles worth of css in every page on that site? what a waste of bandwidth...

Comment: lol. I would not use the plug in that you're using. Since its wordpress and you're not well versed in php I would choose a different plug-in. Modifying the plug-in wouldn't be the best idea esp. since it has no support, the shortcode feature isn't working and you're own your own figuring out why it isn't working. Look for a better plug-in.